# JUnit 5 comparison fails, though IntelliJ contracts

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit, junit5

I have a simple JUnit 5 test case that compares two lists.

JUnit fails the test, but when looking at the differences IntelliJ seems to contratict - see image.
[image]

What do I miss ?

UPDATE:

Here is the test

```
@Test
@DisplayName("Comma separated ids over different lines")
public void commaSeparatedOverLines() throws IOException {
    Path idFile = writeRequirementsFile("ID-234, ID-567" + 
                             System.lineSeparator() + "ID-456");
    List<String> list = new JiraLocalRequirementsReader().readRequirementsId(idFile.toString(), System.lineSeparator());
    assertEquals(Arrays.asList("ID-234", "ID-567", "ID-456"), list);
}
```

and the SUT

```
public class JiraLocalRequirementsReader {

public List<String> readRequirementsId(String file, String separator) throws IOException {
    Path path = Paths.get(file);

    List<String> strings = Files.readAllLines(path);
    if (separator.equals(System.lineSeparator())) {
      return trimResult(strings.stream());
    }
    return trimResult(strings.stream().flatMap(s -> Arrays.stream(s.split(separator))));
  }

  private List<String> trimResult(Stream<String> input) {
    return input.map(String::trim).collect(Collectors.toList());
  }
}
```

Comment: what we miss is an actual test. You are checking for equality for reference of the ArrayList, rather than the actual values stored in it, would be my first guess.

Comment: Did you read about assertArrayEquals ?

Comment: It's a bit hard for us to tell you what's wrong with your test code when you haven't shown it to us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the culprit, the separator I used was `lineSeparator`, which did not split the first two ids (and therefore also the `toString` looked like it was correct). The idea was to use `,`, which split the lines correctly.

With that, the test is green and its ok.

Sorry for bothering and for the bad start with the question.